# Inject sctp packets

Tags: sctp

I've been trying to inject sctp packets in linux environment with no success, 
This is what I have done, I've created an association between two points(one terminal with sctp server and another terminal with sctp client).
Then I sent a char from client to the server and it's been delivered successfully, then I copied the packets from wireshark and put in my source code and incremented the TCN and stream sequence number and send it but i didn't receive it on the sctp server. as you can see below that my packets are exactly the same,

my packet is this:

IP Part
0000   45 00 00 34 00 00 40 00 40 84 3c 44 7f 00 00 01
0010   7f 00 00 01

SCTP Part

0000   0b 5e 0b 59 c2 e5 f8 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 13
0010   fe aa 43 3e 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00 00 64 0a 00 00

then after my packet failed to be delivered to the sctp server i sent with the sctp client just to compare it with my packet and it arrived to the sctp server,

IP Part

0000   45 02 00 34 00 00 40 00 40 84 3c 42 7f 00 00 01
0010   7f 00 00 01

SCTP Part

0000   0b 5e 0b 59 c2 e5 f8 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 13
0010   fe aa 43 3e 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00 00 64 0a 00 00

Regards,
devbag

Answer (score 1):

Your SCTP Message seems badly formatted see [RFC4960](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4960.txt).

Regards

0b 5e :src port

0b 59 :dst port

c2 e5 f8 00 :verification tag

00 00 00 00 : checksum - WRONG

00 : chunk type (payload data)

03 : chunk flags (beginning and end fragment)

00 13 : chunk length

00 10 fe aa : TSN

43 3e : STREAM

00 00 : STREAM Sequence

00 0c 00 00 : PPID

00 00 64 0a 00 00 : User Data